Best puzzles of 2024 Q2 (April - June)?
This question is part of the best-puzzle award series


What are your nominations for the best puzzles, here on Puzzling.SE, of the second  quarter (April/May/June) 2024?


Suggested guidelines for nomination:

Nominate each individual puzzle in a separate answer, so they can be upvoted/downvoted separately.

No more than 3 nominations per person.

Don't nominate your own puzzles.

Before you nominate a puzzle, check to see if someone else has already nominated it. If they have, then add to that nomination as a comment (or edit it) instead of nominating the same puzzle again.

In your nomination, explain what it is that (in your opinion) makes the nominated puzzle such a good one.



Some lists to help jog your memory (your nomination doesn't have to be from these lists):

Algorithmically selected "best of":

Popular puzzles, both in score and in vote to view ratio, from 2024 Q2
Well received puzzles you may have missed from 2024 Q2

Best by votes/views:

Questions with the most votes from 2024 Q2
Questions with the most views from 2024 Q2
Questions with the highest-voted answers from 2024 Q2



Meta-meta issues:
Q: Is this kind of thing allowed on SE?
A: Yes, Photography SE and Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE do something very similar.
Q: What's the point?
A1: To highlight and encourage good practice in a way that goes beyond upvotes.
A2: To work towards building a 'hall of fame' of some of the best puzzles on the site (perhaps to reside on a future puzzling.SE blog) - think of it as our 'greatest hits album'.
A3: To prompt members to put forward their own reflections on what makes a high-quality puzzle.

Should answers be posted as community wiki?

@Lucenaposition No need. Any additional sentiments on a particular puzzle that's already been posted can just be added as a comment beneath the original suggestion.

Footprints in the snow by Amoz
I like this puzzle as it is a question with a red herring, but the answer is nice and simple.

Can you tile a 25 x 25 square with a mixture of 2 x 2 squares and 3 x 3 squares? by Will.Octagon.Gibson
Nice puzzle as it is simple to state and has an elegant and simple solution.
